# Android - Passing a double to a TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

So I'm working on an app to calculate forces for me. It works fine until I try to pass the final number value to a TextView. Here's the code (calc_Click being what is called when a button is clicked):

```
package com.hoodeddeath.physicscalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GravityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gravity);
    }

    public void calc_Click(View v){
        double TEN = 10;
        double NEGELEVEN = -11;
        double G = 6.67*(Math.pow(TEN,NEGELEVEN));
        double TWO = 2;
        String mOneText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.massOne)).getText().toString();
        String aOneText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampOne)).getText().toString();
        String mTwoText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.massTwo)).getText().toString();
        String aTwoText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampTwo)).getText().toString();
        String distText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.distance)).getText().toString();
        String aThreeText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampThree)).getText().toString();

        double mOne = Double.parseDouble(mOneText);
        double aOne = Double.parseDouble(aOneText);
        double mTwo = Double.parseDouble(mTwoText);
        double aTwo = Double.parseDouble(aTwoText);
        double dist = Double.parseDouble(distText);
        double aThree = Double.parseDouble(aThreeText);

        mOne = mOne * aOne;
        mTwo = mTwo * aTwo;
        dist = dist * aThree;
        dist = Math.pow(dist, TWO);

        double total = (G * mOne * mTwo) / dist;

        TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalForceLabel);
        a.setText((int) total);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting and where exactly?

Comment: Can use String.valueOf(double) method or concatenate a blank string with your double.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy. Use this **a.setText(String.valueOf(total));**

```
package com.hoodeddeath.physicscalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GravityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gravity);
    }

    public void calc_Click(View v){
        double TEN = 10;
        double NEGELEVEN = -11;
        double G = 6.67*(Math.pow(TEN,NEGELEVEN));
        double TWO = 2;
        String mOneText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.massOne)).getText().toString();
        String aOneText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampOne)).getText().toString();
        String mTwoText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.massTwo)).getText().toString();
        String aTwoText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampTwo)).getText().toString();
        String distText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.distance)).getText().toString();
        String aThreeText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampThree)).getText().toString();

        double mOne = Double.parseDouble(mOneText);
        double aOne = Double.parseDouble(aOneText);
        double mTwo = Double.parseDouble(mTwoText);
        double aTwo = Double.parseDouble(aTwoText);
        double dist = Double.parseDouble(distText);
        double aThree = Double.parseDouble(aThreeText);

        mOne = mOne * aOne;
        mTwo = mTwo * aTwo;
        dist = dist * aThree;
        dist = Math.pow(dist, TWO);

        double total = (G * mOne * mTwo) / dist;

        TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalForceLabel);
        a.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
 double total = (G * mOne * mTwo) / dist;

 TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalForceLabel);
 a.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Uses the [String.valueOf(double)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm) function

Answer (score 0):

You can set String in the TextView.

Just convert double to String.

```
a.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

For more information about setText parameters.Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType))

Comment: You, my friend, are what fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: approve it as the right answer.Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

First you probably should check that `mOne, aOne, mTwo, aTwo, dist` and `aThree` are not null (- useless for primitive types),

then

```
double total = (G * mOne * mTwo) / dist;
TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalForceLabel);
a.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Comment: it's not possible for a double primitive to be null......

Comment: yes, you are right... In this case, its useless because doubles are 0 by default

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

Use Double.toString

`a.setText(Double.toString(total));`

or you can use the NumberFormat:

NumberFormat nm = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

`a.setText(nm.format(total));`